# How make all card in the same line

Tags: html, css

I'm facing an issue which is I can't make these card at the same line:

[image]

HTML:

```
<div class="row text-center justify-content-center scroll" v-bind:style= "[this.language=='en' ? { 'font-family': 'Poppins'} : {'font-family':'Cairo'}]" >
 <div class="m-3 cat-class" v-for="category in categories" >
 <router-link :to="categoryLink + category.name" :key="category.id"> 
   <div class="img-container">
     <img class="img-dimensions" v-if="category.icon" :src="category.icon.images"/>
    </div>
    <div class="text-center text-wrap mt-1" style="color: black">
     {{ $t(category.name).toUpperCase() }}
     </div>
  </router-link>
</div>
```

CSS:

```css
.scroll {
  overflow-y: auto;
  white-space: nowrap;
  width: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
}

.cat-class {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 64px;
  height: auto;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.img-dimensions {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.img-container {
  width: 64px;
  height: 64px;
}
```

Comment: here's my css
    .scroll{
      overflow-y: auto;
      white-space: nowrap;
      width:100%;
      display: inline-block;
        }
     .cat-class{
     display:inline-block;
     width:64px;
     height:auto;
     text-decoration:none
     }
     .img-dimensions{
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      }
      .img-container{
       width:64px;
       height:64px;   
        }

Comment: Edit the question to add the CSS, not comment.

Comment: You can use vertical-align, or cut off the content like @Arman Ebrahimi suggested.

Answer (score 0):

you must substring content
for exmaple:

```
string.substring(0,7) + '...';
```

Comment: thank you for you answer, but i didn't get you , how this can make images at the same line

Comment: Because the text below the photo is not in line, the size of the characters should be limited
Or use ready-made components like bootstrap`s card

Answer (score 0):

Change `.scroll` to :

```
.scroll {
  overflow-y: auto;
  white-space: nowrap;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: flex-start;
}
```

Is it what you want?

**Edit:**

For example, see the below code with a scroll on the container:

```css
.img-gallery {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: flex-start;
  height: 100px;
  width: 400px;
  background-color: lightblue;
  overflow: auto;
}

.img-gallery>div {
  width: 15%;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="img-gallery">
  <div><img src="https://s4.uupload.ir/files/1-6-5_ssnb.jpg">
    <div>Hello world.Hello world.Hello world.</div>
  </div>
  <div><img src="https://s4.uupload.ir/files/1-6-5_ssnb.jpg">
    <div>Hello world</div>
  </div>
  <div><img src="https://s4.uupload.ir/files/1-6-5_ssnb.jpg">
    <div>Hello world</div>
  </div>
  <div><img src="https://s4.uupload.ir/files/1-6-5_ssnb.jpg">
    <div>Hello world</div>
  </div>
  <div><img src="https://s4.uupload.ir/files/1-6-5_ssnb.jpg">
    <div>Hello world</div>
  </div>
  <div><img src="https://s4.uupload.ir/files/1-6-5_ssnb.jpg">
    <div>Hello world</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: images still aren't in the same line but they moved to top a little bit , my issue is the overflow of text make the image above to moves to the top which make it not at the same line with the other images

Comment: @MonaShazly So you want the image to stay in place and text to move to the downside?

Comment: yes exactly this is what I want

Comment: @MonaShazly I updated my answer. Please try this.

Comment: thank u it worked fine ! , but the div became non scrollable

Comment: @MonaShazly to have a scroll, you should set a height for the container. Please see an example in my answer. Is it what you want for scrolling?